# Unable to retrieve the key of firebase5 using [queryParams]="{category: c.key}" in html

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, angular7

I'm trying to fetch the category name using firebase5's unique key, to display in the url shown below.

[image]

DB structure in firebase

[image]
product.component.html

```
  <a 
  *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async "
  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
  routerLink="/"
  [queryParams]="{category: c.key}"
  [class.active]="category === c.key"
  >{{c.name}}</a>
```

product.component.ts

[image]

product.service.ts

[image]

category.service.ts
[image]

I did try the following fix as per firebase5, but it didn't work for me.

```
<a 
  *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async "
  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
  routerLink="/"
  [queryParams]="{category: c.key}"
  >{{ c.payload.val().name }}</a>
```

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `valueChanges()` on `getCategories()` which will only return the values in the objects and not the actual id's. Two options are to either persist the id in the object as well or using the `snapshotChanges()` like in `getAll()` in your `ProductService`

Your code in `getAll()` is basically what you need to use to get the keys. I tend to store my ids in the object as well just to save the need to do `snapshotChanges()` and use security rules to ensure they are the same.

```
return this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => 
        actions.map(a => ({key: a.key, ...a.payload.val()}))
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Jack Woodward , I updated the code, now it works as expected.